# Nullpointer exception when using @RequestScoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, java-ee-6, managed-bean

i am busy writing a very simple login page using JavaEE6, JSF 2.0 and CDI.
My login page looks as follows (some stuff is removed for clarity):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HomeBase - Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <h:form>
            <div>
                <label>UserID:</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.userid}" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" />
            </div>
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}" />
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the backingbean looks as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject Logger LOG;

    private String userid;

    private String password;

    public String login() {
        LOG.info("Start login procedure.");
        if ("gast".equalsIgnoreCase(userid) && "gast".equals(password)) {
            SessionBean sessionBean = (SessionBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sessionBean");
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserid(userid);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setUsername("Gast");
            sessionBean.setUser(user);
            return "loginSuccess";
        }

        return "loginFailure";
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Now when i call the loginpage it gets correctly displayed. Both inputfields are empty. When in debugmode, i can see the getters for both fieldvalues are getting called. Next, i fill in the fields and press the submit button and an immediate nullpointer exception occurs. Clearly the LoginBean is instatiated the first time (when the page is displayed), but NOT when i press the commandbutton.

What happend?

Comment: The stack trace of the NPE will point you to a line in your login method.

Answer (score 1):

The CDI `@Inject` doesn't work in a JSF `@ManagedBean`. Hence `LOG` remains `null`.

Use CDI `@Named` instead of JSF `@ManagedBean` and make sure that you import `@RequestScoped` annotation from CDI `javax.enterprise.context` package instead of JSF `javax.faces.bean`.

Comment: Injection should work if the injected bean is eligible for injection. Injection might fail for some other reason. My bet is also on the logger.

Comment: I temporarily removed all logging functionality from the code but the problem stays the same. I still get the nullpointer exception. However, when i remove the @ManagedBean and add the @Named, i get a PropertyNotFound exception on the `#{loginBean.userid}` property when i press the loginbutton. The default name of a @Named annotated class is the classname with its first letter uncapitalized, which is exactly "loginBean". So the exception came somewhat unexpected, though not really since it boils down to the same problem as before, there is no instance of the LoginBean class present.